# How to observe last response from server(Websocket)?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, response

I send 5 request to server and i need to do something when all response from server come to me. How can i observe this.  Thanks all!

Comment: You can use NsNotificationCentre when you get the response

Comment: I use, but how can i do it exactly after last response? how observe LAST response?